# Do I need to write the date on the back of a received check when depositing it?

Tags: united-states, check

When I deposit a received check, I need to sign my name on the back of the check at the designated position.

Usually there are two lines in the designated position.
I put my name on the first line.
Do I need to write the date of depositing the check on the second line?

Answer (score 4):

**Changed to answer match the edited version of the question**

No, you do not *need* to write the date of your endorsement, but you can choose to do so if you want to. The bank stamp on the back will likely have the date and perhaps even the exact time when the check was 
deposited.

The two lines are there in case you want to write something like
"For deposit only to Acct# uvwxyz" above your signature (always a
good idea if you are making the deposit by sending the paper check (with or without a deposit slip) by US mail or any other method that doesn't
involve you handing the check to a bank teller).

If you are wanting to get *encash* the check, that is, get cash in
return for handing the check over to the bank instead of depositing the
check in your account, then the rules are quite a bit different.

Comment: If just name, why are there two lines?

Comment: @Tim That might be bank-specific or the top line could be used for writing something like "For deposit only to Acct# uvwxyz" when you are _depositing_ a check instead of cashing it. A bank is entitled to refuse to cash a third-party check even for a bank customer (as opposed to someone walking off the street)  but, as courtesy, they will cash it if you are a customer in good standing and have enough money in your account to cover the check in case it bounces. If you habitually deposit checks from widows of Nigerian bank managers, you won't be getting cash back even for 10% of the face value.

Comment: Yes i deposit checks instead of cashing it.

Answer (score 4):

You do not need to write anything on the second line.  There are a variety of helpful things that you can add, e.g.:

1. For Deposit Only.  This tells the bank to deposit the check into your account and ignore other signatures.
2. Your account number.  Especially useful when added to "For Deposit Only".
3. A countersignature.  This tells the bank to pay the check to someone other than you.

Countersigned checks used to be much more common than they are now.  Someone who didn't have a bank account might ask someone who did to cash a check for them.

See also:  [Four ways to endorse a check](http://www.wikihow.com/Endorse-a-Check) which gives the correct format for endorsing a check in these ways.

Answer (score 2):

Let me just add that while you don't need to write the date received on the back of the check, you could.

Why? Let's say someone was late in paying you and you wanted to document the fact that they were late. I've had late-paying customers send me a check *dated* on the due date but really they just pre-dated the check and sent it 60 days past-due. So let's say I want to establish and document the pattern in case it becomes a future legal issue.

When you deposit or cash a check, an image of the front and back is made and the person or company who issued the check will have those images stored as part of their transaction history. (It used to be that the original, physical, cancelled check was returned to the payer, but that was another era.)

So write the date received on the back next to the endorsement, endorse the check, and take a photo of the front and back (along with the postmark on the envelope) to document that they are a late payer. This way, if it ever becomes a "he said she said" issue you can easily show they have a history of paying late. If the payer looks at their check images they'll see your received date note next to the endorsement.

Granted, this is a lot of trouble for a unique situation. In 20+ years of running a business I've actually had the foresight to do this a handful of times with habitual offenders, and in (only) one case did it come in handy later on. But boy was I glad to have those photos when I needed them.